# highcharts plugin Not supported on IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

My client has IE8 on which I need to represent some chart ...On Chrome the graph displays (I am using highchart plugin for that)

...But on IE 8 this garph is not visible ......

this is my js containing highchart plugin

```
function DrawGphs(container,title,seriesret) {
    //if(area = "Audio")
    containerzxi = container;
    //title = gphobject.title;

    highOptions1 = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: containerzxi
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: title
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: false
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: 16
                    color: '#000000'
                    connectorColor: '#000000'
                    formatter: function () {
                        var val = this.y;
                        if (val == 0) {
                            return '';
                        }
                        return Math.round(this.percentage) + '%';
                        //return val + ' (' + roundDec(this.percentage) + '%)';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>:' + this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{ name: 'Repairs',
            data: [],
            size: '100%',
            innerSize: '60%',
            showInLegend: true
        }]

    };

        highOptions1.series[0].data = seriesret;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(highOptions1);
    }


function getRepairData(selected) {
    var object1 = new Object();
    object1.area = selected;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "IndiaOCR.aspx/GetRepairList",
        data: JSON.stringify(object1),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var cabs = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            //var container = "container4";
            if (object1.area == "Audio") {
                container = "container4";
            }

            if (object1.area == "Stability") {
                container = "powtopdiv";
            }
            if (object1.area == "Touch") {
                container = "touchrepdiv";
            }
            if (object1.area == "Battery") {
                container = "batttopdiv";
            }
            var title = "No. of Repairs";
            //DrawGphs(container, cabs);
            var seriesx = [];
            for (i = 0; i < cabs.length; i++) {
                seriesx.push([cabs[i].TechnicalSymCodeDesc, parseInt(cabs[i].KeyRepairs)]);
            }
            DrawGphs(container, title, seriesx);
        }
    });

}

function getSymptomData(selected) {
    var object1 = new Object();
    object1.area = selected;


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "IndiaOCR.aspx/GetSymptomList",
        data: JSON.stringify(object1),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var cabs = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            //var container = "containerxd";
            if (object1.area == "Audio") {
                container = "containerxd";
            }
            if (object1.area == "3rd Party Applications") {
                container = "appsymdiv";
            }
            if (object1.area == "Stability") {
                container = "powsymdiv";
            }
            if (object1.area == "Touch") {
                container = "touchocdiv";
            }
            if (object1.area == "Battery") {
                container = "battcmdiv";
            }
            //DrawGphs(container, cabs);
            var seriesx = [];
            var title = selected + " Symptom";
            for (i = 0; i < cabs.length; i++) {
                seriesx.push([cabs[i].Symptom, parseInt(cabs[i].Issues)]);
            }
            DrawGphs(container, title, seriesx);
        }
    });

}

function getCategoryData(area) {
    var obj2 = new Object();
    obj2.area = area;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "IndiaOCR.aspx/GetCategorisedList",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj2),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            taged = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;

            // }
            unibiz2 = GetUniqueProductCat();
            for (d = 0; d < unibiz2.length; d++) {
                var title = area + " " + "(" + unibiz2[d] + ")";
                if (area == "Audio") {
                    //for (z = 0; z < trucks.length; z++) {
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "First Products") {
                        container = "audiocon";
                    }
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "Feature Products") {
                        container = "categoryaudi";
                    }
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "Smart Products") {
                        container = "categorysmrt";
                    }
                }
                if (area == "3rd Party Applications") {

                    if (unibiz2[d] == "Feature Products") {
                        container = "appcatdiv";
                    }
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "Smart Products") {
                        container = "appsmrtdiv";
                    }
                }
                if (area == "Stability") {
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "First Products") {
                        container = "powissdiv";
                    }
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "Feature Products") {
                        container = "powcatdiv";
                    }
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "Smart Products") {
                        container = "powsmrtdiv";
                    }
                }
                if (area == "Touch") {
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "Smart Products") {
                        container = "touchcatdiv";
                    }
                }
                if (area == "Battery") {
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "First Products") {
                        container = "battcintdiv";
                    }
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "Feature Products") {
                        container = "battcatdiv";
                    }
                    if (unibiz2[d] == "Smart Products") {
                        container = "battsmtdiv";
                    }
                }
                var newLP = [];
                for (z = 0; z < taged.length; z++) {
                    if (unibiz2[d] == taged[z].ProductCategory) {
                        newLP.push([taged[z].Symptom, parseInt(taged[z].IssuesReported)]);
                    }
                }
                DrawGphs(container, title, newLP);
            }
        }
    });
}

function getComponentData(selected) {
    var objectx = new Object();
    objectx.area = selected;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "IndiaOCR.aspx/GetCompoList",
        data: JSON.stringify(objectx),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            tucks = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            unibix = GetUniqueComponentSym();
            for (t = 0; t < unibix.length; t++) {
                title = selected + "(" + unibix[t] + ")";
                if (objectx.area == "Audio") {
                    if (unibix[t] == "Calls") {
                        container = "container6";
                    }
                    if (unibix[t] == "Music") {
                        container = "contcompsym";
                    }
                }
                if (objectx.area == "Stability") {
                    if (unibix[t] == "All") {
                        container = "powappdiv";
                    }
                    if (unibix[t] == "Communication") {
                        container = "powcompdiv";
                    }
                    if (unibix[t] == "Internet") {
                        container = "powcomdiv2";
                    }
                    if (unibix[t] == "Multimedia") {
                        container = "powcomdiv3";
                    }
                    if (unibix[t] == "Phone Application") {
                        container = "powcomdiv4";
                    }
                    if (unibix[t] == "Third Party") {
                        container = "powcomdiv5";
                    }
                }
                var newLP = [];
                for (s = 0; s < tucks.length; s++) {
                    if (unibix[t] == tucks[s].Component) {
                        newLP.push([tucks[s].IssuesDesc, parseInt(tucks[s].ConsumerReporting)]);
                    }
                }
                DrawGphs(container, title, newLP);
            }
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#wrapper').width($(window).width() * 0.7);
    $('.main-menu-span').width($(window).width() * 0.2);
    $('#gmenu').tabs({
        //selected = $('#maindiv').text();

        activate: (function (event, ui) {
            var active = $("#gmenu").tabs("option", "active");
            selected = ($("#gmenu ul>li a").eq(active).text());
            //alert(selected);

            getRepairData(selected);
            getSymptomData(selected);
            //GetProductData(selected);
            //GetData(selected);
            // getGPHComment(selected);

            //            $('#Button1').click(function () {
            //                $(this).removeClass('editbut');
            //                $(this).addClass('savebut');
            //                
            //            });

            getCategoryData(selected);
            getComponentData(selected);
            getGPHComment(selected);
            if (selected == 'Audio') {
                GetDecibelData();
            }
        })
    });
    mainOCRTrend();
    mainCIdata();
    GetCIMPproducts();

    $('.editbut').click(function () {

        //                 $(".ui-button-icon-primary", this).toggleClass("ui-icon-disk ui-icon-pencil");
        //                 $(this).prev("textarea").attr('id').disabled(); ;
        //                 return false;
        //             }, function () {
        $(".ui-button-icon-primary", this).toggleClass("ui-icon-pencil ui-icon-disk");

        if ($(".ui-button-icon-primary").hasClass("ui-icon-disk")) {
            //var oldcmtn = $(this).prev("textarea").val();
            // $('#oldcomment').val(oldcmtn);
            $(this).prev("textarea").focus();
            if ($(this).prev('textarea').val().length != 0) {
                com = $(this).prev('textarea').attr('id');
                oldcmnt = $('#' + com).val();
                //$('#oldcomment').val(oldcmnt);
                //var oldCmt = odcmnt.html();
                //input
            }



        }
        if ($(".ui-button-icon-primary", this).hasClass("ui-icon-pencil")) {

            //var tstext = com.value();
            com = $(this).prev('textarea').attr('id');
            if ($('#' + com).val().length == 0) {
                var comon = $('#' + com).val(oldcmnt);
                saveTxt(com, comon);
            }
            else {
                var conon = $('#' + com).val();
                saveTxt(com, conon);
            }
            //alert($(this).prev("textarea").attr('id'));
            //saveTxt(com);
        }
        return false;
    });


    var oldcmnt = "";
    var com = "";
    selected = "Main"
    //var dtab = new Object();
    //dtab.area = selected;
    getGPHComment(selected);


});


//Main Tab 

var cabs = new Object();
function mainOcr() {
    var highOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Top OCR'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'India Claim Rate'
            },
            min: 0
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value) + '%';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '%' + '<br/>';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal'
            align: 'bottom'
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: []
    };
    unibikis = GetUniqueArea();
    highOptions.xAxis.categories = GetUniqueYearPer();
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(highOptions);
    for (var d = 0; d < unibikis.length; d++) {
        newLP = [];
        var aName = unibikis[d];
        for (j = 0; j < cabs.length; j++) {
            if (unibikis[d] == cabs[j].Area) {
                newLP.push([cabs[j].Area, parseFloat(cabs[j].ClaimRate)]);
            }

        }
        chart.addSeries({
            name: aName,
            data: newLP
        }, false);
        chart.redraw();
    }

}

function mainOCRTrend() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'IndiaOCRImprovement.aspx/mainOCR',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            cabs = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            mainOcr();
        },


        error: function () { alert('Server Error!!!'); }

    });
}

var trucks = new Object();
function mainCIdata() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'IndiaOCRImprovement.aspx/mainPageConsumer',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            trucks = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            mainCIGraph();
            mainCIPGraph();
        },
        error: function () { alert('Server Error!!!'); }
    });
}

function mainCIGraph() {
    highOptions1 = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1'
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: '2013 Repair Data'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                    distance: 16
                    color: '#000000'
                    connectorColor: '#000000'
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<span style="color:' + this.point.color + '">' + this.y + '</span>';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>:' + this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{ name: 'Repairs',
            data: [],
            size: '100%',
            innerSize: '60%',
            showInLegend: true
        }]

    };
    unibikiz = GetUniqueMPCItype();
    for (var d = 0; d < unibikiz.length; d++) {
        var newLP = [];
        //var aName = unibikiz[d];
        for (j = 0; j < trucks.length; j++) {
            if (trucks[j].CIType == '2013 Repair Data') {
                newLP.push([trucks[j].Area, parseInt(trucks[j].CI)]);
            }

        }
        highOptions1.series[0].data = newLP;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(highOptions1);
    }

}

function mainCIPGraph() {
    highOptions1 = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2'
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Consumer interaction'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: false
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                    distance: 16
                    color: '#000000'
                    connectorColor: '#000000'
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<span style="color:' + this.point.color + '">' + this.y + '</span>';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>:' + this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{ name: 'Repairs'
            data: []
            size: '100%'
            innerSize: '60%'
            showInLegend: true
        }]

    };
    unibikiz = GetUniqueMPCItype();
    for (var d = 0; d < unibikiz.length; d++) {
        var newLP = [];
        //var aName = unibikiz[d];
        for (j = 0; j < trucks.length; j++) {
            if (trucks[j].CIType == 'Consumer interaction') {
                newLP.push([trucks[j].Area, parseInt(trucks[j].CI)]);
            }

        }
        highOptions1.series[0].data = newLP;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(highOptions1);
    }

}
var tags = new Object();
function GetCIMPproducts() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'IndiaOCRImprovement.aspx/mainPageConsumerPro',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            tags = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            mainCIProdGraph();
        },
        error: function () { alert('Server Error!!!'); }
    });


}

function mainCIProdGraph() {
    highOptions2 = {
        colors: ['#7FF8D2', '#FF9BCE', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: 'container3'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Consumer Interaction - Top Products Specific Areas'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'grey'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                        'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    formatter: function () {
                        var val = this.y;
                        if (val == 0) {
                            return '';
                        }
                        return val;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: []
    };

    unibiz = GetCIMPSym();
    highOptions2.xAxis.categories = GetUniqueMPProduct();
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(highOptions2);
    for (var d = 0; d < unibiz.length; d++) {
        var newLP = [];
        var aName = unibiz[d];
        for (j = 0; j < tags.length; j++) {
            if (unibiz[d] == tags[j].Area) {
                newLP.push([tags[j].Product, parseInt(tags[j].CI)]);
            }

        }
        chart.addSeries({
            name: aName,
            data: newLP
        }, false);
        chart.redraw();
    }
}

var gpdata = new Object();
function getGPHComment(selected) {
    var obj = new Object();
    if (selected == "3rd Party Applications") {
        selected = "Applications";
    }
    obj.area = selected;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'IndiaOCRImprovement.aspx/GetGraphCommentDB',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            gpdata = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            txtdisp(obj);
        }
    });
}

function txtdisp(ar) {
    //if (ar.area == 'Main') {
    var area = ar.area.toLowerCase();
    for (i = 0; i < gpdata.length; i++) {


        if (gpdata[i].GraphType == 'ClaimRate') {
            $('#' + area + '_cr').empty();
            $('#' + area + '_cr').append(gpdata[i].Comment);
        }
        if (gpdata[i].GraphType == 'CI') {
            $('#' + area + '_ci').empty();
            $('#' + area + '_ci').append(gpdata[i].Comment);
        }
        if (gpdata[i].GraphType == 'TopIssues') {
            $('#' + area + '_ti').empty();
            $('#' + area + '_ti').append(gpdata[i].Comment);
        }
    }
    //}
}
function saveTxt(com, coj) {
    var oject1 = new Object();

    if ($('#' + com).text().length == 0) {
        alert('Please Enter some text');
        $('#' + com).focus();
        //$('.edibut').addClass('ui-icon-disk');
        $('.editbut').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-disk'} });
        $('#' + com).append(coj);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        oject1.text = $('#' + com).text();
        var comsplit = com.split('_');
        var ard = comsplit[0].capitalize();
        if (comsplit[1] == 'ci') {
            oject1.graphtype = 'CI';
        }
        if (comsplit[1] == 'cr') {
            oject1.graphtype = 'ClaimRate';
        }
        if (comsplit[1] == 'ti') {
            oject1.graphtype = 'TopIssues';
        }
        oject1.area = ard;
        //oject1.text = $("#" + com).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'IndiaOCRImprovement.aspx/SaveGraphComment',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(oject1),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function () { alert('Server Error!!!'); }
        });
    }
}

function GetDecibelData() {
    $.ajax({

        url: 'IndiaOCRImprovement.aspx/GetDecibelData',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            tags = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            for (var u = 0; u < tags.length; u++) {
                var table = $("#audtable tbody").append("<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + tags[u].ConsumerLocation + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + tags[u].Level + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + tags[u].MaxdbLevelObserved + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + tags[u].City + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>");

            }

        },
        error: function() { alert('Server Error!!!'); }
    });
}
```

One suggestion I got is use jquery version below 1.9.1 ..Now I am using 1.9.0 through CDN link ...still No Luck

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: What error message are you getting (if any)?

Comment: I don't see any related code to Highcharts. It's required too. Also, [read FAQ](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#not-showing-in-explorer).

Comment: I have add highchart function plugin ...

Comment: At the beginning please isolate your example and replicate it as live demo (with harcoded your data), whcih will allow us to check if the reason of your problem is highcharts part.